# В чем разница между if else и switch?

Tags: javascript

Заметил интересный момент, хотелось бы узнать почему так происходит.
Вот пример номер 1:

```js
var people = {
    1:{name:'Вася'},
    2:{name:'Петя'},
    3:{name:'Сережа'},
}; 
let key = 1;
if(key==1)
{
    let man = people[key];
    console.log(man);
}
else if(key==2){
     let man = people[key];
     console.log(man);
}       
else
{
    let man = people[key];
    console.log(man);
}
```

Результатом будет `{ name: 'Вася' }` . Это правильно и хорошо, меня полностью устраивает результат.
Пример 2:

```js
var people = {
    1:{name:'Вася'},
    2:{name:'Петя'},
    3:{name:'Сережа'},
}; 
let key = 1;
switch(key) {
    case 1:
        let man = people[key];
        console.log(man);
        break;
    case 2:
        let man = people[key];
        console.log(man);
        break;
    default:
        let man = people[key];
        console.log(man);
        break;
}
```

Как на мой взгляд, результат должен быть тот же, не чего существенно не изменилось, но результатом будет ошибка нечто вроде - `Identifier 'man' has already been declared`.
Почему так?)
Я делаю предположение что разница кроется на этапе компиляции, и switch case в отличии от if else заглядывает во все свои case, и исполняет код только в нужном случае, и вот в тот момент когда заглядывает, находит ошибку в синтаксисе, так как получается что несколько let переменных объявляются друг за другом... Как то так вообщем.
Какие Ваши мысли по этому поводу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что, нужно создавать области видимости через фигурные скобки (`{}`), тогда  переменная `man` будет существовать только в пределах своей области.

Попробуйте:

```js
var people = {
    1: {name:'Вася'},
    2: {name:'Петя'},
    3: {name:'Сережа'},
}; 
let key = 1;
switch (key) {
    case 1: {
        let man = people[key];
        console.log(man);
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        let man = people[key];
        console.log(man);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        let man = people[key];
        console.log(man);
    }
}
```

Comment: Действительно, все оказалось проще, забыл скобочки поставить)